# Html Population Api

Tags: javascript, html, api, population

In the meantime, I have a question related to programming. I am creating this website about countries and I am wondering what can I do to have an up-to-date population of a certain country. Do you have any idea where I can start or what to do? Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free [Countries API](https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v2-name), you can fetch the data about the countries that you want to list, including ist population;

For example:
fetch => https://restcountries.com/v2/name/usa
Will return a object containing many info about the country including:

- population
- language
- name
- flag (url for the flag image)

Answer (score 0):

An API is probably what you want.  There are several with information you are looking for.  One option might be [Countries API](https://rapidapi.com/aptitudeapps/api/countries33/) on RapidAPI.  The free option will give you country name, capital, population, ISO codes, and some UN geocode information.  There are also paid options with much more data.